# Google Cloud MySql WHERE IN not working properly

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, mysql-5.7

Using WHERE IN with a temporary table feed as a parameter, MySql query engine returns a completely unexpected result.

```
CREATE TABLE MDC_Customer (StoreId char(20), Name nvarchar(100));
CREATE TABLE MDC_Caixa (Data datetime, CaixaId int, StoreId char(20), Revenue DECIMAL(15,2));

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StoreRev (Stores nvarchar(44));

TRUNCATE TABLE StoreRev;

INSERT INTO StoreRev SELECT StoreId FROM MDC_Customer WHERE StoreId IN ('00013');

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CaixaRev (CaixaID int, StoreID char(20));

TRUNCATE TABLE CaixaRev;

INSERT INTO CaixaRev 
    SELECT CaixaId, StoreId 
    FROM MDC_Caixa CX 
    WHERE CAST(CX.Data AS date) BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-01' 
        AND CX.StoreID IN (SELECT StoreID FROM StoreRev);

SELECT * FROM StoreRev;
SELECT * FROM CaixaRev;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE StoreRev;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE CaixaRev;
```

Actual Result:
MySql evaluates CX.StoreID IN (SELECT StoreID FROM StoreRev) as true, instead of throwing an 'INVALID SYNTAX ERROR';

Expected Result:
MySql should throw an 'INVALID SYNTAX ERROR' reporting that there's no 'StoreID' field in StoreRev temporary table;

Comment: If you run this in mysql locally what happens? BTW you could add details of the tables used but not defined in the code block provided.

Comment: Your insert statements are missing the column lists. While not required, it sure makes it plain what you are trying to do, and makes mistakes easier to spot.

Comment: I do not see where a syntax error would occur in your code, presuming that StoreID exists in MDC_Customer. I don't see where your code references StoreID in StoreRev.

Comment: @P.Salmon, I have defined the tables used. Thank you! ;o)

Comment: @SloanThrasher, the bug here is that MySql should promptly throw a syntax error in the INSERT INTO CaixaRev statement. There's no field named StoreID in the StoreRev temporary table and MySql instead of throwing the error, evaluates the WHERE IN as true.

Comment: @P.Salmon, just tested using mysql locally and got the same unexpected result.

Comment: Why? It may never evaluate that part of the where if any of the previous parts are false (because of the AND statements).

Comment: Got that @SloanThrasher, but the previous part is actually true with my sample data and the returned result ignores the second WHERE IN that should filter for just the StoreId's in the temporary table.

Comment: The part of your WHERE clause: ```CAST(CX.Data AS date) BETWEEN '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-01'``` will likely never be true since you are checking a date against two strings.

Comment: @SloanThrasher, that part is working properly for me.

Comment: Can you try the suggestion of actually creating that column in StoreRev and see what happens?

Comment: Just a note it makes no difference if the tables are permanent rather than temporary and if the data test is removed.

Comment: And curiously if you substitute abb for storeid an unknown column error is thrown.

Comment: Try: `... CX.StoreID IN (SELECT StoreRev.StoreID FROM StoreRev);`.

Comment: @wchiquito that works but a bug surely?

Comment: @P.Salmon: Probably `StoreID` is interpreted from the `MDC_Caixa CX` table, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8fb3b2e7749838a1a0dc51a4d04702c) example.

Comment: @wchiquito Agreed, that's about where I was before your helpful interjection.

Comment: I agree with @wchiquito, probably it's interpreted from `MDC_Caixa`. @mmarques, did you try it or did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Iñigo, unfortunately I managed to workaround it. Surely a bug in MySql from versions 5.x, up to 8.x. - Thank you very much for your time here guys!